# Differentiated color fills in geom_histogram()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a histogram with differentiated colors according to a categorical variable, the data I am using is given by:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
  
df <- data.frame(var = rnorm(1000, 50, 10))
df$cat <- cut(df$var, breaks= c(0, 20, 50, 70, 100), labels = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

What I would like to do is to plot the distribution of my `var` variable using `ggplot2` and filling with different colors the bars for each category marked by the `cat` variable. The histogram I am currently ploting is given by:

```
library(ggplot2    
df %>% ggplot(aes(var)) +
      geom_histogram(fill = "navy",
                     alpha = 0.5) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = c(20, 50, 70),
                 linetype = "dashed")
```

I would like to know, how to adjust this piece of code to fill each of the intervals shown by the vertical dashed lines.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please include at least a sample of the data (use `dput` to output a dataset) so we can help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first try to infer what your data is like since you did not supply this in your question:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(69)

x <- data.frame(x = rnorm(5000, 50, 10))

ggplot(data = x,
       aes(x = x)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "navy",
                 alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(30, 70, by = 10),
             linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

That's close enough for demonstration purposes.

It would be very difficult (though not impossible) to keep the plot the shape it is and color differently between the lines. It would also make little sense to have different colors within bins. However, it is fairly easy to do (and makes more sense) if you line up the bins with the vertical lines. Effectively we just manually bin and tabulate the data and plot it however we like:

```r
df <- setNames(as.data.frame(table(1.25 + 2.5 * floor(x$x/2.5))), c("bin", "count"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(bin)), y = count, fill = bin)) +
  geom_col(width = 2.5) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(30, 70, by = 10),
             linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rep(c(rep("gray75", 3),
                               rep(c("yellow", "gold", "orange", "red"), each = 2),
                               rep("gray75", 4)), each = 2),
                    guide = guide_none()) + 
  labs(x = "x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>